# $(...).accordion not a function error in drupal7 views accordion module

Tags: views, navigation

I had enabled a views accordion for a field in view. On displaying it in a page its not working and I got an error "$(...).accordion is not a function". Can any one help me in solving this?

Comment: post your error message

Comment: @ Bala I got this error in console of firebug  " TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function "

Comment: What views accordion did you install? Does `your_site_root/misc/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js` exist?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module and set jQuery of your website to `1.7+`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your jQuery libraries are creating conflict. Try to use 'jQuery' instead of '$'.
Else you can use a simple line of code to avoid jQuery library conflict.
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page.
This link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Astha said, example:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(function(){
              var H = jQuery(".owl-item").height();
              jQuery(".plate").height(H);
          });
  </script>
```

Every `jQuery` used to be a `$`.